# Simple Seconds Timer using javascript and display in my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Simple problem is Just to show that the time is running out.. For example There are only 10 seconds in the time, Show it in my Webpage that the time is 10.. 9.. 8.. 7.. 6.. 5.. 4.. 3.. 2.. 1.. and thats it.. its very simple.. i dont have an idea in javascript because im more in php codes.. I've tried this script

```
setInterval(function() {
var timer = $('span').html();
timer = timer.split(':');
var minutes = timer[0];
var seconds = timer[1];
seconds -= 1;
if (minutes < 0) return;
if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
    minutes -= 1;
    seconds = 59;
}
else if (seconds < 10 && length.seconds != 2) seconds = '0' + seconds;
if ((minutes < 10) && ((minutes+'').length < 2)) minutes = '0' + minutes;
$('span').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
}, 1000);
```

and My html Tag like this

```
<font face="tahoma" size="2" color="red">
<span>00:10</span>
</font>
```

But its not working, but in JS fiddle.. it's working i wonder why when i put it in my webpage the 10 seconds is not moving.. Thank you for the help

Comment: Based on this `but in JS fiddle.. it's working` did you try enclosing the JS within `<script></script>` tag?

Comment: You should maybe also use $('span').text() as opposed to .html()

Comment: you worte using javascript in your title, but you also using jQuery for this, did you implement the jQuery library? if so, maybe a : `$(document).ready(function(){});` is missing?

Comment: Are you sure that on your page just one span-node exist? Orherwise you should give your span a class or ID.

Comment: ...just as a side-note: length.seconds makes no sense in this case!

Comment: Yes i enclosed my JS with <script> tag..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956692/simple-seconds-timer-using-javascript-and-display-in-my-html/19959361#19959361

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you are importing jquery
  
correcting the error NAN

```
 setInterval(function() {
var timer = $('span').html();
timer = timer.split(':');
var minutes = timer[0];
var seconds = timer[1];
    if(seconds!="00" || minutes!="00"){
        seconds -= 1;
        if (minutes < 0) return;
        if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
            minutes -= 1;
            seconds = 59;
        }
        else if (seconds < 10 && length.seconds != 2) seconds = '0' + seconds;
        if ((minutes < 10) && ((minutes+'').length < 2)) minutes = '0' + minutes;
        $('span').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/Evmyp/4/